# ORO MIgration from 3.1.19 to 4.1.2

Tags: orocrm

We are migrating from ORO 3.1.19 to 4.1.2 and we are having issues with the migrations.

```
$ php bin/console --env=prod oro:migration:load --force --show-queries
Process migrations...
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\LoadEntityConfigStateMigration
  > Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\UpdateBundleVersionMigration
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\RefreshExtendCacheMigration

    Prepare entity config
    Clear extended entity cache
    Dump the configuration of extended entities to the cache
    Clear entity metadata cache
    Warm   up entity metadata cache

    In RuntimeReflectionService.php line 63:

    Property Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\Attachment::$account_8d93c122 does not exist
```

We tried to clear the cache, entity-config cache and no success

```
 php bin/console --env=prod oro:entity-config:cache:clear
 php bin/console --env=prod oro:entity-config:cache:warmup
```

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

## EDIT

We can see that the `Attachment::$account_8d93c122` is found by the Reflection during the initial container creation, but not during the entity-cache warmup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution/workaround was to run `oro:entity-extend:cache:check` before the cache clear

```php
class RefreshExtendCacheMigrationQuery {
// ....
    public function execute(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->commandExecutor->runCommand(
            'oro:entity-extend:cache:check',
            [],
            $logger
        );

        $this->commandExecutor->runCommand(
            'oro:entity-extend:cache:clear',
            [],
            $logger
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using doctrine ORM services (@doctrine, @entity_manager, etc.) when entity metadata is not ready.

Usually, the error appears when ORM is used in compiler passes or migrations.

Comment: I carfully analysed the call stack and the request is comming directly from `oro:entity-extend:cache:clear`. There is also additional fields in the `ClassMetadataInfo->associationMappings` that dont exists in the `Attachement` class like `opportunity_f89bd07c` and `products_and_services_818222f3`

Comment: See edit above, i was able to find a workaround that works.